# How to map <C-Space> to ESC

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex

I am using

```
nnoremap <C-Space> i

inoremap <C-Space> <Esc>
```

to map  to Esc. It works for all file with any extension but it doesn't work for the files with ".tex" extension ( I am using Vim-latex suite). I don't know why?

Comment: Use `:map` and check if <c-space> is bind to something else (maybe some plugin)?

Comment: It says "<C-Space>". It doesn't account the second line

Comment: You can try using the tag `<unique>` in your mapping to have an error raised if another plugin try to overwrite it.

Comment: @CharlesGueunet,  Could you show me how to use this command?

Comment: @ofenerci You can try: `map <unique> <C-Space> <Esc>`. It should return `E277: mapping already exists for...` if overwritten, with the corresponding file and line.

Comment: @CharlesGueunet, We are closing in :) Now I got the cryptic message "E227: mapping already exists for <80><fc>^D". But in which file or package?

Comment: @ofenerci in my case it is written on the line juste above the error message. Don't you have it ?